# GridView loses column contents during PostBack

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, postback, viewstate, templatefield

I am having an issue with the behavior of a **GridView** between post backs.

The real problem comes from a **TemplateField** I define in the markup at **column[0]** with a child **CheckBox** control. Things work fine for the first, and second search executions. However, at some point between the second execution and anything that causes a post back there after, I lose the contents of the TemplateField.

Its only the the contents of the column and not the whole column itself that gets removed. The TemplateField is present in the source and shows a formated column at position 0 of the table.

**CODE:**

```
protected void ExecuteSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lb_SelectedFields.Items.Count == 0) { return; } //if no selected fields

    //Generates custom SQL query based on user inputs and column Selections
    BuildQuery(); // sets txbSqlText.Text = to the SQL string

    DataTable Table = SqlAdapter.Select(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(txbSqlText.Text));

    for (int i = gv_SearchResults.Columns.Count - 1; i > 0; i--) 
    { gv_SearchResults.Columns.RemoveAt(i); } //removes all the columns except[0]

    foreach (ListItem Item in lb_SelectedFields.Items) //adds all the user defined columns
    {
        //Column object that is able to find the column definition
        Column Col = ColumnsBasedOnFocus.FindColumName(Item.Value); 

        if (Col.Type == "HyperLink") { gv_SearchResults.Columns.Add(CreateHyperLinkField(Col)); }
        else { gv_SearchResults.Columns.Add(CreateBoundColumn(Col, true)); } //true is if the column is visable
    }

    gv_SearchResults.DataSource = Table;
    gv_SearchResults.DataBind();
}
```

**ASP.NET:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_SearchResults" runat="server" GridLines="None" CellSpacing="0"
    CellPadding="0" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="TABLE_LIGHTBLUE" Width="100%">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="TABLE_LIGHTBLUE_HEADERROW" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <center>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_SelectAll" runat="server" OnClick="SelectAll" Text="All" CssClass="TEXT_SMALL" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_Placeholder" runat="server" Visible="false" /></center>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <center>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_Select" runat="server" Visible="true" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_AssetGID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("i_GID") %>' /></center>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Could you provide your aspx code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a link that describes a similar situation.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/104994/templatefield-in-a-gridview-doesnt-have-its-viewstate-restored-when-boundfields-are-inserted#details

They describe a bug in ASP.Net code that fails to properly manage view states with template fields in dynamically generated grid views.

Answer (score 0):

Basically TemplateFields can't be properly restored from ViewState, and if you modify the ASPX-declared columns programmatically, it can't create them from the declarations either.
The only solution I could get working was to create a new class deriving from TemplateField that in the constructor set the ItemTemplate to an ITemplate-derived class, which means having to define the template programmatically instead of declaratively.
You can also rebind the gridview on each postback but that's its own can of worms.